# Joomla JImage & SP Simple Portfolio: Copying and rename file without manipulating it?

Tags: php, html, joomla, content-management-system, portfolio

I have problems with Image compression in Joomla JImage with the SP Simple Portfolio Plugin, because the images are doubled in size on the hard drive compared to the original. But `createThumbs()` is not necessary. The pictures have already the right pixelratio and don't need any further manipulation.

Is there a way to copy the pictures, like SP does, without manipulating it? Just copying the file and rename it. Because i don't want to chance all the php Code of the plugin. This would be the easy solution. Just copying it to a directory and rename it to the right filename. JImage `toFile()` didn't worked because the size is doubled as well...

From original SP Simple Portfolio Code in controller/thumbs.php:

```
$image = new JImage($image);
$image->createThumbs($sizes, $cropratio, $path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it by myself and it works like charme :). Maybe someone is interested in how to get an 1:1 image copy in the SP Portfolio:

```
            $resultTemp = end(explode('/',$image));
            $result = str_replace('.jpg', '', $resultTemp) ;

            $newName  = $path.'/'.$result.'_1000x750.jpg';
            copy($image , $newName);
```

Instead of original code which manipulates the picture quality and size:

```
            $image = new JImage($image);
            $image->createThumbs($sizes, $cropratio, $path);
```